# PHP Array, Then check if in data

Tags: php, arrays

I'm checking every possible thing in the array to see if it contains something from the data specified.

Array:

```
$dogs = [
    "terrier" => "Terrier",
    "german_shepard" => "GS",
];
```

Code:

```
if ($stmt->execute()){
    while ($request = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        foreach($dogs as $x => $x_value){
            if (strpos($request['Data'], $x) !== false) { // This bit!!
               $dog = $x_value;
            } else {
               $dog = 'Unknown dog';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then have a list, It can detect the first one in the list fine, but others it just calls 'Unknown dog' EG:

> 1 - Terrier
>
> 2 - Unknown Dog
>
> 3 - Unknown Dog

I want it to appear like:

> 1 - Terrier
>
> 2 - GS
>
> 3 - GS

I want the list to appear for each value found.

Comment: You could var_dump or print_r $request to see what you are getting. Showing us would help us help you...

Comment: My first thought is: do you have `german_shepard` in the database?

Comment: It's still unclear. What are the values stored in the database? And based on what logic are you willing to print these list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$dog` variable for each item it checks in `$dogs`, so if there is anything that doesn't match after the one that does match, it will set it back to `'Unknown dog'`. You should set `$dog` to a default value before your loop, and only overwrite it if it is found.

```
$dog = 'Unknown dog';
foreach($dogs as $x => $x_value){
    if (strpos($request['Data'], $x) !== false) { // This bit!!
        $dog = $x_value;
    }
}
```

There may be more than one value in `$dogs` that matches a particular instance of `$request['Data']`. If you use this code, `$dog` will be set to the *last* value from from `$dogs` that matches `$request['Data']`. If you want it to be set to the *first* matching value, then add a `break;` after `$dog = $x_value`; If you want something other than first or last, it will need to be more complex than this.

Comment: Side note: try breaking both loops to prevent unnecessary iterations. +1

Comment: Damn it sorry you are correct. I was making the answer with a break and then realized what this does...

Comment: @FirstOne I added some explanation of how `break` could be used here.

Answer (score -1):

You may use PHP's native [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function:

```
$dog = 'Unknown dog';
$key = in_array(strtolower($request['Data']), $dogs);
if($key >= 0){
    $dog = $dogs[$key];
}
```

Comment: There is a _case-insensitive_ `strpos`: [**stripos**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).